# Does the current company try to ''squeeze'' the work out of me?

Tags: company-culture, stress

At this point I am working in a start-up company and I feel like they're trying to 'make the most of me'. In other words, I need to be productive over **90 - 95%** of the time and to deliver results as fast as I can. Tasks keep coming and I hardly deal with them. My supervisors are watching me each time I stand up to rest my eyes or to get a coffee. The salary is not motivating at all, but the office conditions are good.

Another problem is that I keep *improving(?)* / changing the code until the supervisor is fully satisfied - this means that there's very little 'me' in the code at the end. I have under 2 years of experience in development, but I don't think that I produce rubbish code that needs to be changed every time.

I was wondering if in other mid-range (not Amazon / Google etc.) IT Companies the conditions are the same; if there's someone watching you at every step.

Comment: Any remotely decent development company will have some sort of code review process.

Comment: I'm talking about ~5 iterations through the code. ''Improvements'' that don't seem to be really necessary...from my point of view.

Comment: Workt to understand why they are considered necessary -- maintainability, clarity, edge cases, etc. There are many bad habits we get into that really should be eliminated in production code.

Comment: It is my first job indeed as I'm fresh out of University. Other devs are treated the same and they're roughly the same age as me. I'm concerned since our University teachers warned us that some employers might hire students and push them really hard because the students are 'unaware about how things go in IT'

Comment: To be brutally honest: this sounds like you still need to adjust to working life. That includes getting used to 8/9-hour days, being productive during those hours, writing maintainable software, etc. If you got through university without ever having to put in a lot of work that's going to be a tough adjustment. But absent further details, we can't tell whether your manager is simply monitoring new graduates *as he should* or if you've stumbled upon a company operating more like an Orwellian police state. Either way, this is more of a rant than a question.

Comment: Honestly, you need to get over the idea that there should be some "me' in your code. The code is the company's code, ti will be changed by many people through the years, it is not your code, it should not reflect your personality and you don;t own it. It should do its job in a similar fashion as the rest of the code which makes it easier to maintain for everybody else. Yes even if that is not the best method. If you have 1000 things done one way and then your stuff done a completely different way, your code is going to be harder for others to understand and maintain.

Comment: And a start-up in particular is likely to demand both high quality _and_ high productivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a case of micromanagement, caused by too many Chiefs and not enough Indians. It may be that your supervisor(s) literally have nothing better to do than look over your shoulder and revise your code. Makes me wonder why aren't they coding, too, if there is so much work coming down the pipe.

It could also be a trust issue. There might be some reason for which they believe your work must be verified. Is this how they treat other devs or just you? Do you think they have any reason to treat you this way (more bugs than anticipated, etc.)?

It could be an insecurity issue -- your code might actually be nearly as good or even better in some ways than what your 'supervisor' could produce. If this causes them insecurity, they may be using patronizing as a tactic to implicitly keep you in a subordinate position.

Finally, it could be a *you* issue -- your code actually sucks (in some respect), and they actually try to help you improve it, and objectively do so by scrutinizing it.

Solutions:

- If you feel secure in your experience and do not see switching positions/employers as too problematic, you could raise the issue with your supervisor directly, and if that produces no progress (they get defensive and only increase scrutiny), go to their supervisor.
- If it is at all plausible that your supervisors might actually be more experienced/knowledgeable than you, then you could use this as a learning opportunity, as well as a chance to practice humility, attention, and ability to listen and learn. Rather than seeing them as looking over your shoulder, you could treat the situation as the opposite -- you producing output, then letting them show you how to make it better.

If the issue is the supervisor's personal insecurity, then calling them on it by asserting your independence and competence will only fan the flames. The only way out of this is to accept them as a superior and submit to whatever requests come from them and do them without any complaint, until they become more comfortable, OR leave the team/organization for another job. Of course, there is no guarantee you won't run into the same situation in the future.

I would recommend to take on a learning attitude and try to ride this one out a while longer. Perhaps in the end you will learn more about coding (at the very least, how *not* to code -- also very valuable), as well as about yourself and your own work style (and how far your buttons can be pressed before you snap). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some answers to your questions:

o) We are a few developers and we are treated the same way. 
o) One supervisor codes, the other is not and keeps thinking about how to add more tasks to the board in order to increase traffic etc. 
o) It should not be a trust issue since we are all struggling to increase the company revenue.

Comment: If you are all treated the same way, then why are you defensive about them making modifications to your code? Especially in a startup, your goal should be to produce the best product that you as a team can produce. This means either they are adding quality and you should try to learn from them, or they are not adding quality and their time could be better spent. If you're new to the field of software development there will be a LOT of things that seem trivial to you but are important to the overall picture. Try to learn from their corrections and adapt!

Answer (score 9):

> I was wondering if in other mid-range (not Amazon / Google etc.) IT
>   Companies the conditions are the same; if there's someone watching you
>   at every step.

I work at a mid-range company. And I designed and built up the infrastructure of my team from ground up using the tools completely of my choice. Yeah, the CTO and the CEO have helped me address the stability and quality (as I was a recent grad), but gave me complete freedom with the selection of the tools.

So, every company has a very different engineering cultures. So, it cannot be generalized so easily.

> changing the code until the supervisor is fully satisfied

**Yes**. In a startup (or in fact, every company), you can't get away with mediocre code. Even though if you are an experienced dev, you **have** to write really good code, keeping the quality and execution of the code at production in mind.

And managers are there to ensure that you write good code, and yeah code reviews can be frustrating. But, trust me; they are worth it.

Answer (score 5):

You're at a startup. I've done a few startups in my career, and your experience is not all that unusual. Your supervisors watching you each time you stand up to rest your eyes or get a coffee is a little over the top, but it's not a normal workplace. It's a startup. It won't always be this way, but for now, it is. Sink or swim.

I think it is a little worrisome that your code goes through 5 iterations before it is acceptable. Five is excessive, which leads me to believe that there is something you aren't getting. You must figure that out and correct it, because they are not going to keep you around if they constantly have to send your code back for fixes.

Lastly, forget about the whole "me" thing with your code. Lots of people will touch your code. Lots of people will modify your code. You work at a startup, so every line of code you have written is likely to be replaced within a couple of years. I've been coding a long time, but usually I have no idea who wrote some piece of code I'm working on. The only time I care is when there is something confusing that I want to ask you about. That's the way it should be. There are only two reasons I should be able to tell who wrote something: It's extraordinarily good, or it's extraordinarily bad.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The supervisors watching you every time you get up thing is a little.. strange.. to say the least, however, the note about "me" in your code and 5 iterations is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the company is investing about you in the sense that accept the loss of more reviews, even unnecessary, waiting for you to recognize the differences and what is the logic behind the request for a further revision.

Your next task might be to anticipate the demand already pointing to the release. You could annotate as comments the code of your review steps performed independently.